# Reducing nesting with itertools.product()

Tags: python, nested-loops, python-itertools

I know that itertools.product() is an efficient and fast solution for resolving nesting loops. However, its using becomes more tricky, if there are additional statements in not innermost loop, like this:

```
for i in ...:
    #- Do some stuff here
    for j in ...:
        if j % 2 == 0:
            #- Do more stuff if j is even
        for k in ...:
            #- Do stuff in innermost loop
```

More or less straightforward refactoring with `itertools.product()` works and indeed reduces the nesting, but it has serious performance issues.

```
import itertools, timeit

s1 = """\
n = 10
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
for i in lst:
    a = 2 + 2
    for j in range(n):
        if j % 2 == 0:
            a = 2 * 2
        for k in range(n):
            a = a"""

print('Nested loops runtime:', timeit.timeit(stmt = s1, number = 100000))

s2 = """\
n = 10
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
idx_i_prev = idx_j_prev = -1
for (idx_i, i), (idx_j, j), k in itertools.product(
enumerate(lst), enumerate(range(n)), range(n)):
    if idx_i != idx_i_prev:
        a = 2 + 2
    if idx_j != idx_j_prev:
        if j % 2 == 0:
            a = 2 * 2
    a = a
    idx_i_prev = idx_i
    idx_j_prev = idx_j"""

print('\'itertools\' runtime:', timeit.timeit(stmt = s2, number = 100000))
```

This outputs:

```
Nested loops runtime: 7.883076536934823
'itertools' runtime: 17.23935990303289
```

Therefore, my question: Is there a way of refactoring nested loops without harming the performance?

Comment: Maybe it's because you are doing more work in the `product` version of your code? In that version you are `enumerating` both `lst` and one of the `range(n)`, in the nested-for-version you are not.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That is because in case of the `product` I need these indices to know, when the iteration on every utterable start over again. In case of nested loops the enumeration is of course unnecessary.

Comment: I'd simply avoid this refactor. `itertools.product` is only really a better idea if all of the code is in the innermost loop, like you wrote.